# Why memoir does not respect babel when printing \thedate

Tags: memoir, babel, metadata

Why does `memoir` fail to recognize language specific dates (with `\today`) outside its own `\maketitle`?

It works fine when I add such metadata after `\begin{document}`, but I've never done this before (should I and if so, why?)

See the following MWE

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage[brazil]{babel}
\title{A title}
\author{A. Uthor}
\date{\today}
\begin{document}
\maketitle

thedate: \thedate
\end{document}
```

[image]

As opposed to `article` (needed to print `@date` here before `\maketitle` since it is erased afterwards):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[brazil]{babel}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\thedate{\@date}
\makeatother
\title{A title}
\author{A. Uthor}
\date{\today}
\begin{document}
thedate: \thedate

\maketitle
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Just put `\date{\today}` *after* `\begin{document}`, otherwise `\thedate` is defined when `\selectlanguage{brazil}` has not yet been issued.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`memoir` defines `\thedate` by “freezing” the argument to `\date` *at the moment the declaration is issued*.

When `\date` appears in the preamble, no language has been selected yet (so `\today` expands to the current date in American English format). The language switch to Brazilian Portuguese happens only during processing of `\begin{document}`.

Solution:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage[brazil]{babel}
\begin{document}

\title{A title}
\author{A. Uthor}
\date{\today}

\maketitle

thedate: \thedate
\end{document}
```

or (but I don't recommend doing so)

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage[brazil]{babel}

\title{A title}
\author{A. Uthor}
\selectlanguage{brazil}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

thedate: \thedate
\end{document}
```

[image]

A more drastic measure is to patch the `\date` command in order to delay the definition of `\thedate`:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage[brazil]{babel}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd\date
 {\protected@xdef\thedate{#1}}
 {\AtBeginDocument{\protected@xdef\thedate{#1}}}
 {}{}
\makeatother

\title{A title}
\author{A. Uthor}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

thedate: \thedate
\end{document}
```

Comment: Nice! But I'll have to wait till tomorrow to accept `:)`